# Question closed without answer

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Could someone tell me why was my question closed? It says off topic but I don't understand why. I thought I described the problem well..
It's my second question which has been closed and I wonder what I do wrong. How should the question look like to be on topic?

[link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507292/backlink-relevance)

Comment: It's not programming question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [question you're referring to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507292/backlink-relevance) is not a programming question. As such it's off-topic. There is really no recommendation to make to have this question be on-topic.

The other question that was closed (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15902825/simplest-free-cms-for-existing-websites), was closed because it's asking for CMS recommendations. Recommendation questions, often referred to as "shopping questions" are also off-topic for the site because they are considered to be "not constructive".

The canonical reference for this second type of question is this blog post: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: Also worth adding that the SEO question *might* be on topic at http//webmasters.stackexchange.com/ -- I'm not familiar with that site very much, so I'm not sure what exactly qualifies, or if this SEO question meets their standards, but it's worth checking out that site, reading the FAQ, looking at SEO questions there, and deciding whether your question makes sense there.

Comment: I think I understand where I went wrong now. Thank you for the answer and explanation.